# Android TV app created using Flutter got rejected by playstore for "Missing DPad functionality"

Tags: flutter, dart, android-tv

App created using flutter for android TV is getting rejected.I have made such that it supports D-PAD and it is working fine in TV emulator.

My main.dart file has ActivateIntent(),

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCcYY.png)

On all other pages I have wrapped scaffold with Shortcuts and Used Actions widget for specifying where focus should be next onpress on any keys from D-PAD.

[Shortcuts use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6O8a.png)

[Actions use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIe9x.png)

However playstore still cant detect that I have handled dpad buttons.

[androidmanifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OkWN.png)

I have added requirements as in androidmanifest.xml file. I have setup navigation using dpad which is working in TV emulator. However app is still rejected.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.